# Redirect sub-domain to specific directory using .htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had a problem earlier and asked this question: [PHP Image Upload using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542392/php-image-upload-using-post)

I found out that the cause of that problem was my domain redirection. I was using a redirect (Server emulation) in my domain panel which is unable to handle file uploads.

By searching for a solution I found this: [sub-domain directory redirection using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122821/sub-domain-directory-redirection-using-htaccess)

I enabled the mod_rewrite module and tried this .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.de/sub/directories/$1 [R=301,L]
```

subdomain.domain.de has a A-DNS entry set to the IP of my server. The root directory of my server needs authentification but the directory I want the subdomain point to doesn't. I'm unsure if the redirection works, but when I open the subdomain it asks for authentification.

How can I redirect a subdomain to another directory on the server without having the user to authentificate?

Comment: how about your authenticate? Is http basic authentication ?

Comment: Yes, it's basic HTTP authentification using the apache config file in sites-available directly. My .htaccess contains nothing but the above and it's placed in the root directory. The subdirectory named "sub" in my above code has no authentification as set in the apache config file too.

Comment: You can try modifying this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7390331/1163642 according to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted using virtual hosts by following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

I also had to remove the .htaccess file. Besides changing the ServerAlias/Name and DocumentRoot in the new sites-available config file I had to change nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, You must use virtualHost for subdomain because your basic HTTP authentication executed before htaccess. 
Another way, you can config basic HTTP authentification in htacess file after RewriteRule, do not config in apache config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it working using virtual hosts.